# Join and transpose 2 datetime rows into column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['2023-06-01 09:55:00', '2023-06-02 09:55:00', '2023-06-01 10:00:00', '2023-06-02 10:00:00']
price_1 = [16.00, 16.45, 16.00, 16.79]
price_2 = [16.91, 17.44, 16.95, 18.10]
data = {
    'price_1': price_1,
    'price_2': price_2
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(index))

print(df)
```

I don't know if I asked the right question but what I basically need is to turn dataframe below:

```
                     price_1  price_2
DATE                                     
2023-06-01 09:55:00  16.000000  16.917621
2023-06-02 09:55:00  16.454790  17.440297
2023-06-01 10:00:00  16.001549  16.955189
2023-06-02 10:00:00  16.792508  18.100698
```

into:

```
                     price_1_09:55  price_2_09:55 price_1_10:00 price_2_10:00
DATE                                     
2023-06-01           16.000000      16.917621     16.001549     16.955189
2023-06-02           16.454790      17.440297     16.792508     18.100698
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve the problem

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['2023-06-01 09:55:00', '2023-06-02 09:55:00', '2023-06-01 10:00:00', '2023-06-02 10:00:00']
price_1 = [16.00, 16.45, 16.00, 16.79]
price_2 = [16.91, 17.44, 16.95, 18.10]
data = {
    'price_1': price_1,
    'price_2': price_2
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(index)).reset_index()
df['time'] = df['index'].dt.time
df['index'] = df['index'].dt.date
df = df.pivot(index='index',columns='time',values=['price_1','price_2'])
df.columns = [f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" for i in df.columns.values]
df.head()
```

It is giving below output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extract the date and time components as MultiIndex and reshape:

```
out = (df
   .set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.normalize(),
                                         df.index.strftime('_%H:%M')]))
   .unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
   .rename_axis('DATE')
)

out.columns = out.columns.map(''.join)
```

Output:

```
            price_1_09:55  price_2_09:55  price_1_10:00  price_2_10:00
DATE                                                                  
2023-06-01          16.00          16.91          16.00          16.95
2023-06-02          16.45          17.44          16.79          18.10
```